# Deploying ASP.NET 4.* MVC and Web API applications to Linux server

Tags: asp.net, linux, web-deployment

Is there any way of Deploying ASP.NET 4.* MVC and Web API applications to Linux server? I searched and read about Docker but I think that is for .NET 5.

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do that with some bricolage on a Linux-based Docker image.

This helped me a lot: https://github.com/junalmeida/docker-mono-web

Basically, you can host your web application with nginx, but you also need fastcgi-mono-server4.

The dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM mono:latest


RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y \
      iproute2 supervisor ca-certificates-mono fsharp mono-vbnc nuget \
      referenceassemblies-pcl mono-fastcgi-server4 nginx nginx-extras \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* \
  && echo "daemon off;" | cat - /etc/nginx/nginx.conf > temp && mv temp /etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
  && sed -i -e 's/www-data/root/g' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# this copies nginx configuration files to the proper directory
COPY nginx/ /etc/nginx/
```

In the link above, the `supervisord` command is used to start both nginx and fastcgi-mono-server4.

It is configured in a **supervisord.conf** file like the following, in which the **--appconfigdir** specifies the root folder of your application:

```
[supervisord]
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log
logfile_maxbytes = 50MB
nodaemon=true
user=root

[program:mono]
command=fastcgi-mono-server4 --appconfigdir=appconfig --socket=unix --filename=/var/run/mono-fastcgi.sock --printlog --name=mono
user=root
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0

[program:nginx]
command=nginx
user=root
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

and launched with this command:

```
/usr/bin/supervisord -c supervisord.conf
```

(a folder contains a configuration for nginx, too).